# exclude a category from a search on a specific page

Tags: functions, categories, query

I have a search bar on 2 pages in my site and on my page called archive I want to exclude a category called economics (id - 9) from the search. I have placed this in my functions.php file:

```
function archive_search_filter( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() ) {
  $query->set( 'category__not_in' , '9' );
  }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'archive_search_filter' );
```

and it works perfectly but I want to only have this implemented on the page called archive. If I try an if statement with is_page('archive') along with this it is not working and I'm not sure of a solution. I'm wondering if the functions.php loads before it can tell what page it is and if there is another way to get this to work.

Comment: Did you mean page archive or the post archive?

Comment: it's just a page called archive, it isn't either of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `pre_get_posts` is called *after* you leave the page, so you must also test to see if the search was done from there and for that you can use [`wp_get_referer()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer)

So *(in theory, sorry I haven't the time to test this)* you could have

`if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && wp_get_referer() == "http://www.example.com/archive" ) {`

Hope that helps

*PS: Always add a `!is_admin()` check to make double-sure you're not effecting admin queries... belt & braces!*

Comment: thanks Peter this worked for me and thanks for the tip about !is_admin()

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code.

```
function archive_search_filter( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_page( 'archive' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'category__not_in' , '9' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'archive_search_filter' );
```

Comment: thanks but no luck with that either